# asp.net: c#/javascript user needs to confirm before submitting

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

i have a webform on asp.net c# page

the user enters data into the form. there are textboxes and there's a treeview

when the user presses the SUBMIT button, i would like all the data to be shown to him for his confirmation. the user should have the option to continue with the submit OR to go back to the form and edit the data.

is there an all ready out of the box way to do this>? if not, what is the easiest way to implement this?

Comment: have you found any answer for this?

Answer (score 16):

If it's a button web control, you can add `onClientClick` and a confirm javascript call.

```
<asp:button Id="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" 
       onClientClick=" return confirm('Are you sure?')" 
       onClick="btnSubmit_click" />
```

Comment: @baia thank you i would like all the data to be shown to him for his confirmation.

Comment: @user558922 you can define a custom javascript method and formulate a message from all the filled out values and use confirm to display it. I don't think there's anything out of the box to display filled out data for confirmation.

Comment: @baia ok let me know if you stumble upon something

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple button and call a function which if your condition == true send your data or submit data using ajax

```
 <input type="button" onclick="TestBeforeSubmit();"value="">
    
    
    function TestBeforeSubmit()
           {
               if //Conditions == false)
               {
                   
               }
               else
               {
                   $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       url: "//YourUrl",
                       dataType: 'json',
                       data: //YourData,
                       success: function (result)
                       {
                       },
                       error: function (result) {
                           alert("Something went wrong");
                       },
                   });
    }
```

Comment: "Try this" does not make for a good answer. You should explain how and why this solves their problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).